# How to find transparent background location in image?

Tags: javascript, python, html, image, pyautogui

I have a HTML code where I will place text in the transparent background area of an image.
Since I don't know how to get the exact coordinate on the fly using JS or HTML, the only solution I was able to start was using the `pyautogui` Python library. But I was also not being able to find the correct transparent area coordinate.

PSD and PNG files shared from my OneDrive: [Pictures](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgnBdF_BgESzjfg33R9YFCAEcbIKhA?e=gQODRC)

I will pass the coordinate to this style:

```
.code-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 500px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I tried with Python, but can be another solution as well.
My Python code:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import pathlib
from PIL import Image

# Load your PNG file and cut out the desired image
Img = os.path.join(os.path.sep, pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), 'test.png')

image = Image.open(Img)
image.show()

alpha_channel = image.split()[-1]  # get the alpha channel
transparent_pixels = []

for x in range(image.width):
    for y in range(image.height):
        if alpha_channel.getpixel((x, y)) == 0:
            transparent_pixels.append((x, y))
            pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)

print(transparent_pixels)
```

The output was not in the transparent area, and I don't know how or why.

So my question is, how can I find that **transparent area coordinate** to pass to my HTML code no matter the app opens the image or the Windows theme?

On Photoshop I can see the background:

[image: Photoshop]

When I open with Paint I can see the white area:

[image: Paint]

But when I open the image using the `PIL` Python library, it opens from "Photos" Windows app, and the color there is black in this case:

[image: Windows app]

And the color found using the `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()` function is: `X:  966 Y:  634 RGB: ( 28,  32,  44)`

**----- UPDATE -----**

What I need is to place a code where in the midle of this transparent background area, but this is what I am getting:

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from PIL import Image


image_url = 'transparent_area.png'
image = Image.open(image_url).convert('RGBA')
all_pixels = image.load()
image_width, image_height = image.size[0], image.size[1]
all_transparent_pixels = []

for i in range(image_width):
    for j in range(image_height):
        p = all_pixels[i, j]
        if p[-1] < 255:
            all_transparent_pixels.append([i, j])

left_top_corner = all_transparent_pixels[0]
right_bottom_corner = all_transparent_pixels[-1]

print(left_top_corner, right_bottom_corner)
```

Below test on your image (which is 1.24 MB).
Coordinate problem solved

*Log from PyCharm:*
[image: log from PyCharm]

*Coordinates from Photoshop*
[image]

**UPDATE** for second question

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                background-image: url('transparent_area.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

            .code-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                width: calc(671px - 1px - 369px);
                height: calc(627px - 1px - 588px);
                position: absolute;
                left: 369px;
                top: 588px;
                border: 1px dashed #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="code-container">
            <span>this is code</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Screenshot of RESULT*

[image: Screenshot of RESULT]

without border change:
`width: calc(671px - 1px - 369px)` for `width: calc(671px + 1px - 369px)`, `height: calc(627px - 1px - 588px)` for `height: calc(627px + 1px - 588px)` and delete `border: 1px dashed #000;`

**NEW UPDATE**

For getting all 4 coordinates use output from code below:

```
print('left_top_corner (x: ' + str(left_top_corner[0]) + ', y: ' + str(left_top_corner[1]) + ')')
print('right_bottom_corner (x: ' + str(right_bottom_corner[0]) + ', y: ' + str(right_bottom_corner[1]) + ')')
```

in css it will be:

```
width: calc(right_bottom_corner.x - 1px - left_top_corner.x);
height: calc(right_bottom_corner.y - 1px - left_top_corner.y);
```

**LAST UPDATE**

I managed to solve your question.
But coordinates are not one of the unknown problems. In addition to the coordinates, there are many other unknowns variables: paddings, applying on background image a css-property `scale()`, using `<br>` as paddings. When changing which it will also be necessary to pick up the values `left` and `top` for `.code-container`

*changes:*

```
        .code-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: calc(671px - 1px - 369px);
            height: calc(627px - 1px - 588px);
            position: absolute;
            left: calc((100% / 2) + 226px - 369px );
            top: calc(172px + 588px);
            border: 1px dashed #000;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .image {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        transform: scale(1.3);
        z-index: 999;
        }
```

Comment: But how am I going to get the transparent backround coordinates from this command? This is what I got from your answer `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=1024x1024 at 0x1B84611BFA0>`

Comment: With this line we will get access to the Alpha channel! See the answer again...

Comment: I got coordinates from your query, but when I pass the output to the `.code-container`, the text is somewhere else instead of where it should be. I just updated my question with how it became.

Comment: That DISLIKE that you put to my answer, well, it really interferes with continuing further assistance. And one piece of style (.code-container) is not enough, the whole page is needed to understand the problem.

Comment: The dislike was due to first answer, but I already took care of that. Thank you for your hard work on this answer. The coordinates is on the first vertex of the rectangle is [369,588], I might need to find the 4 vertex and then finding the midle of that box to place the text. Is there an easy way now?

Comment: See another update, your code is not needed... All 4 coordinates you have

Comment: See new update for geting 4 coordinates

Comment: Really amazing dedication to your answer, thank you! Somehow on mine is different, I uploaded my HTML code to the same OneDrive folder: [Pictures](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgnBdF_BgESzjfg33R9YFCAEcbIKhA?e=gQODRC)

Comment: See last update, but ideally you need to completely rewrite the all page code. So that when making any changes, it would not depend on the other unknown variables described by me in the "Last UPDATE"

Comment: Just to understand a bit from your answer since I changed my transparent area now. How did you find the numbers for this two lines? `left: calc((100% / 2) + 226px - 369px );` and `top: calc(172px + 588px);`

Comment: 369px and 588px - coordinates, 226px and 172px - coefficients are selected manually. If something changes in the design, the coefficients will need to be selected again. Why did I say that such an option is not very correct